# Unable to prevent $stateChangeStart from transitioning to a login page before user can be re-authenticated from Server

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, authorization

I am having trouble in my AngularJS application with re-authenticating my user on a page refresh.  I have followed a guide [here](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec) to implement auth throughout my application, however, I am struggling when the user refreshes the page. Basically what is happening is that in the `$stateChangeStart` module, my code checks to see if the User is authenticated yet, and if not, transition to the Login page. However, because the App takes sometime to re-authenticate the user back from the Server, it automatically jumps to the login page before the User is logged back in.

I have added an `AuthResolver` just like the instructions and have added a `resolve` to my routes:

```
       .state( 'home', {
            url: '/',
            resolve: {
                auth: function resolveAuthentication( AuthResolver ) {
                    return AuthResolver.resolve();
                }
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.index.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            data: {
                requiresLogin: true,
            }
        })
```

In my `app.run()` module, the first thing I do is try and re-auth the user:

```
    // Check to see if a token exists
    if( AuthService.getToken() != null ) {


        // Get the authed user details from the Server
        AuthService.getAuthUser( AuthService.getToken() )
            .then( function( user ) {


                // Create a new Session
                Session.create( user.ObjectGUID, user.Groups );


                // Set the current user
                $rootScope.currentUser = user;


            }, function( error ) {


                console.log(error);


            });


    }
```

Then in my `$stateChangeStart()` module, I run the following check:

```
        // Check to see if the new state requires the user to be logged in
        if( toState.data.requiresLogin ) {


                    // Check to see if the user is authenticated already
                    if( AuthService.isAuthenticated() ) {  //<== Always returns false because it's still waiting for the `AuthService.getAuthUser()` to resolve.


                        console.log( 'user authenticated' );


                    } else {


                        console.log( 'user not authenticated' );


                        // Broadcast a not authenticated message
                        event.preventDefault();


                        $rootScope.$broadcast( AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated );


                    }


        }
```

However, the `resolve` in my home route never gets called, because my App jumps instantly to the Login page through `$rootScope.$broadcast( AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated );` on a page refresh

Comment: When external login page is used, imho usual flow is:
1. Server checks if user logged, else redirects to login.
2. Frontend redirects to login if any request returns 401.

I am not sure why u ever tried to do any check in state change ? What case it covers?

Comment: That was how it was documented in the guide I followed. I am not keeping any session state on the Server, I am simply just passing a JWT back to my front end and verifying authentication via that.